# Print EPS into PDF in .Net4.5

Tags: imagemagick, pdf-generation, ghostscript, eps, aspose.pdf

I am developing a winform application with .Net 4.5 framework. I am able to create a PDF file, but unable to print an EPS format drawing onto PDF. I have tried the following-

Itextsharp,ghostwriter,LibreOffice,Latex ,epstopdf,PStill,ASPOSE ,spire.pdf, imagemagick, imageglue

In all this either they don't support EPS format or dll is not available. Can anybody guide for a full proof method to do this or if anyone have been successful in such an activity?[I don't want to convert it to JPG(tried it) as it degrades the picture quality]

Comment: Ghostscript will happily take EPS and produce a PDF file. "gswin64c -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf input.eps". Can't see any reason why ImageMagick wouldn't do the same.The others I have no clue about. Of course, you will have to have Ghostscript installed.....

Comment: I am sorry, I am not aware of the language used for "gswin64c -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf input.eps". I need to do this in Winform application. Can you guide me related to my situation.

Comment: I know nothing about winform, that's a command line from the shell, presumably you can launch a shell application.

Comment: With shell scripting into picture I am trying to fire that from my application. Need some assistance- What will be the command for an eps file at location "D:\Testing\AIM.eps"

Comment: Will this --   "gswin64c -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf 02040001_A1_P1.eps"                   be the correct syntax of the command needed for an eps to pdf conversion, because it isn't generating the pdf [executed successfully]

Comment: For a 64-bit install of Ghostscript, yes. For a 32-bit install you would need gswin32c. You might want to put a full path spec for both the input and the output files, as otherwise the output will be created in the current working directory, the input file read from there as well and I've no idea where that would be. Have you tried this from the actual command shell, or just from your applictaion ? Try it from the command shell **first** to be sure its all working.

Comment: Hello KenS, for using the dll in my application,which method of installation of Ghostscript is correct-
1. Install from Nuget and use it in my application [Worked for other referenced dll] OR
2. Install it from "http://www.dlldownloader.com/ghostscript-dll/" and follow its steps

Which method will help me to use it in my application and to test the shell script above?

Comment: I know nothing about either of these.. The command line I stated uses the Ghostscript executable and requires Ghostscript to be installed. Note that Ghostscript is licenced under the AGPL and you may not simply distribute the DLL.

Comment: I have downloaded the dll and tried running "gswin64c -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf 02040001_A1_P1.eps" in CMD, it gives error-"gswin64c is not recognized as an internal command"

Comment: Why do you think that downlaoding a DLL is going to make a shell command work ? You need the executable, which requires the Ghostscript installation to be complete. Delete the DLL you just downloaded, go to ghostscript.com and get the installer from there. I have just reported the dlldownloader site, they are offering to download the Ghostscript DLL in a way which is not compliant with the AGPL, I expect they will be receiving a legal 'cease and desist' order shortly.

Comment: And if you want to use Ghostscript in your application, read the AGPL and make certain you are conforming with the terms of the licence.

Comment: Its a free software as per the AGPL. Can you provide the link for downloading ghostscript installer?

Comment: AGPL does not mean 'free'; the site is offering an AGPL piece of software without making it clear that its licenced under the AGPL, nor does it distribute a copy of the AGPL or make it clear where to go for the original source, all of which are required (at a minimum). The site is clearly in breach of the licence terms. I already told you where to go to download Ghostscript; www.ghostscript.com

Comment: Hi Pratik, Aspose.Pdf is working on providing support for EPS to PDF conversion and we hope to have this feature in our API.

PS, My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Hello Nayyer,great to hear directly from Aspose. Help me with your id so that I can show my code used with Aspose and the problem I am facing with it. I hope my issue gets resolved with Aspose.Id- aggarwalpratik7@gmail.com